# How creating a list of variables that can adjust numbers of variables depends on length of values list

Tags: python, list

I want to make a list of variables that is always equal to the length of the list of values.

```
**Example**

list1 = [0,1,2]
return
[a0,a1,a2]
```

a0 = 0, a1 = 1, a2 = 2

```
list2 = [10,20,30,40]
return
[b0,b1,b2,b3]
```

b0 = 10, b1 = 20, b2 = 30, b3 = 40

Comment: Sounds like a [X-Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Maybe you want to explain the context a bit.

Comment: Rather than `exec`, you can consider just creating a dictionary with the keys being a0, a1, and so on.

Comment: Variable names shouldn't have indexes built in. If you find yourself going that way, just use a list and index that. So rather than `a0`, `a1` and `a2`, just have a list bound to the variable `a` that you index to get `a[0]`, `a[1]` and `a[2]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can do this, but I'm not sure I'd recommend it:

```py
list1 = [0,1,2]
for i, v in enumerate(list1):
    exec(f"a{i} = {v}")
print(dir())
print([a0,a1,a2])
```

Output:

```
['__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'i', 'list1', 'v']
[0, 1, 2]
```

The repeated calls to the [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) function have added `a0`, `a1` and `a2` to the current local scope as shown by the output of the call to [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir). Printing `[a0, a1, a2]` confirms that these variables have the values in `list1`.

As @
[user2736738](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3796113/user2736738) has suggested in a comment, your question seems to indicate that the root problem you are trying to solve may be better addressed by a different approach.

**UPDATE**: Here's some additional code to further illustrate how the variables and the list of variables will behave upon subsequent updates while also addressing OP's query in a comment, namely "I want the output to be a list of variables ... how to create the list while not type it manually?":

```py
list1 = [0,1,2]
for i, v in enumerate(list1):
    exec(f"a{i} = {v}")
exec(f"new_list = [{','.join('a'+str(i) for i in range(len(list1)))}]")
print(dir())

print("new_list:")
print(new_list)

print(','.join('a'+str(i) for i in range(len(list1))) + ':')
exec(f"print({','.join('a'+str(i) for i in range(len(list1)))})")

if len(new_list) > 0:
    a0 = 99
    print(f"new_list after updating a0 to {a0}:")
    print(new_list)

if len(new_list) > 1:
    new_list[1] = 66
    print(f"new_list after updating element at index 1 to {new_list[1]}:")
    print(new_list)
    print(','.join('a'+str(i) for i in range(len(list1))) + f' after updating element at index 1 to {new_list[1]}:')
    exec(f"print({','.join('a'+str(i) for i in range(len(list1)))})")
```

Output:

```
['__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'i', 'list1', 'new_list', 'v']
new_list:
[0, 1, 2]
a0,a1,a2:
0 1 2
new_list after updating a0 to 99:
[0, 1, 2]
new_list after updating element at index 1 to 66:
[0, 66, 2]
a0,a1,a2 after updating element at index 1 to 66:
99 1 2
```

The second `exec()` call starting `exec(f"new_list = ...` will do what you asked in your comment. However, I would again urge you to consider whether this is truly helpful to you in your larger goals, and alert you to the disconnect between this list of variables and the variables themselves.

As you can see, assigning a new value to the variable `a0` has no effect on `new_list`, the variable referring to the list `[a0, a1, a2]`, and assigning a new value to `new_list[1]`, the element at index 1 within that list, has no effect on the variable `a1` which was used to initialize that list.

Comment: The way you're using `i` in the loop is almost certainly a mistake waiting to happen. You probably want to `enumerate` the list or maybe iterate on a `range`, rather than relying on every value in the list being its own index.

Comment: @Blckknght Yep, agreed. I typed too quickly in my first draft. Have updated the answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: Agree with the comment. I realize that the question I asked doesn't fix the root cause a all.